# Using dplyr to calculate a new column based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a column from a calculation that is based on several conditions from two data frames but I dont really know how to best arrange it.

I will try reproduce an example to get everyone understand my problem:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ProductType=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                  ProductGroup=c('C1', 'C1', 'G1', 'G2'),
                  Scenario=c('J', 'J', 'K', 'K'),
                  Group=c('J', 'J', 'K', 'K'),
                  dataOut=c(21, 18, 17, 10))

df2 <- data.frame(ProductType=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                  ProductGroup=c('E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
                  Scenario=c('J', 'J', 'J', 'J','K', 'K', 'K', 'K'),
                  Base=c('M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4','M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4'),
                  Level=c('P', 'S', 'P', 'S','P', 'S', 'P', 'S'),
                  dataOut=c(21, 18, 17, 10, 210, 180, 170, 100))
```

My dataframes are structured as above. I want calculate with the dataOut values an insert the result into a new column (or row if thats easier) while some conditions are fulfiled.
E.g.
"Calculate df1$dataOut * df2$dataOut where Scenario and ProductGroup are the same.Group in df1 and Level in df2 should also correspond.

I would be great if anyone could give me a hint for how to best perform it. I stuggle to create a dplyr syntax for it...

Already many thanks,

Carlo

Comment: There are no observations that concomitantly match `Scenario`, `ProductGroup` and `Group` and `Level`...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for the family of join functions to perform those matches you refer. Here are two examples using `inner_join()` and `full_join()` from `{dplyr}` package.

The demonstration is not very interesting though because the data provided as example does not allow matches between the two data frames `df1`  and `df2`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
df1 <- data.frame(ProductType=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                  ProductGroup=c('C1', 'C1', 'G1', 'G2'),
                  Scenario=c('J', 'J', 'K', 'K'),
                  Group=c('J', 'J', 'K', 'K'),
                  dataOut=c(21, 18, 17, 10))

df2 <- data.frame(ProductType=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                  ProductGroup=c('E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
                  Scenario=c('J', 'J', 'J', 'J','K', 'K', 'K', 'K'),
                  Base=c('M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4','M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4'),
                  Level=c('P', 'S', 'P', 'S','P', 'S', 'P', 'S'),
                  dataOut=c(21, 18, 17, 10, 210, 180, 170, 100))

full_join(df1, df2, by = c("ProductGroup", "Scenario", "Group" = "Level")) |>
  mutate(data_out.xy = dataOut.x * dataOut.y)
#>    ProductType.x ProductGroup Scenario Group dataOut.x ProductType.y Base
#> 1              A           C1        J     J        21          <NA> <NA>
#> 2              B           C1        J     J        18          <NA> <NA>
#> 3              C           G1        K     K        17          <NA> <NA>
#> 4              D           G2        K     K        10          <NA> <NA>
#> 5           <NA>            E        J     P        NA             A   M1
#> 6           <NA>            F        J     S        NA             B   M2
#> 7           <NA>            G        J     P        NA             C   M3
#> 8           <NA>            H        J     S        NA             D   M4
#> 9           <NA>            E        K     P        NA             A   M1
#> 10          <NA>            F        K     S        NA             B   M2
#> 11          <NA>            G        K     P        NA             C   M3
#> 12          <NA>            H        K     S        NA             D   M4
#>    dataOut.y data_out.xy
#> 1         NA          NA
#> 2         NA          NA
#> 3         NA          NA
#> 4         NA          NA
#> 5         21          NA
#> 6         18          NA
#> 7         17          NA
#> 8         10          NA
#> 9        210          NA
#> 10       180          NA
#> 11       170          NA
#> 12       100          NA

inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("ProductGroup", "Scenario", "Group" = "Level")) |>
  mutate(data_out.xy = dataOut.x * dataOut.y)
#> [1] ProductType.x ProductGroup  Scenario      Group         dataOut.x    
#> [6] ProductType.y Base          dataOut.y     data_out.xy  
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that for your problem you need to use a left_join for example :

```
left_join(df1 %>% rename(dataOut1 = dataOut), 
          df2 %>% rename(dataOut2 = dataOut), 
          by=c("Scenario","ProductGroup","Group","Level")) %>%
   mutate(calculation = dataOut1 * dataOut2)
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your comments! I could finally solve my issue by using the left_join approach.

Best rgards,
Carlo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).